# Xcode instance method is not being called from another class

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

This time I really don't know where to look for this problem.

I have an UIViewController with an embedded UITableView.
I've added the UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource to my header file.
Inside the implementation file I've imported the header file of another Class I use to read/write to my DB.

In the "numberOfRowsInSection" section of my implementation file there's this code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
DbOperations *medi = [[DbOperations alloc] init];
self.orari = [medi ProssimeMedicineGrouped];

return [self.orari count];
}
```

I've added a breakpoint to the start of this method and then I've seen that the method "ProssimeMedicineGrouped" is not being called at all.

Yesterday it was working without problems. The only change I've made is changing the ViewController from UITableViewController with just the table, to an UIViewController with the tableView embedded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set the tableView's `delegate` property to `self`? And one more thing, I don't think it's a good practice to create the `DbOperations` object in this method as it's called when the tableView needs more information about the data source and this can happen more than once.

Comment: In the "viewDidLoad" section I have [tableName setDelegate:self]. But it's still not working. I didn't know about what I did was a bad practice, I will change it. I've noticed another thing: in the "viewDidLoad" I'm calling another method of the same DbOperations class, and this is skipped too.

Comment: Is the numberOfRowsInSection: method called at all? If it's not, then make sure the numberOfSectionsInTableView: returns something >0

Comment: Yes, the "numberOfRowsInSection" method is called, but as it is not calling the other DbOperations method, it returns 0.

Comment: can you show the declaration of the orari property and also make sure if ProssimeMedicineGrouped method actually returns something. And are you using ARC?

Comment: orari is declared as a NSMutableArray (strong, nonatomic) and then synthesized in the implementation file. The method ProssimeMedicineGrouped is not being called. I've set a breakpoint to the begin of that method and the program never reaches it. And yes, it returns a mutable array with 3 objects, so the row number should be 3. I'm using ARC.

Comment: Hmm, try to debug to see the medi instance is not nil when initialized. Could be something with the initializer...

Comment: Ok I think I've got it. It's totally my fault and I feel stupid now. I forgot that I've reset the simulator, so Xcode created another empty document folder and then copied my empty db from the bundle to the documents folder. I didn't noticed because I set the breakpoint after the sqlite3_step, so that's why the program never reached it. So sorry for the time I make you waste.